# Python isdigit is not recognizing numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

So in Python, I am using `.isdigit()` to check whether if it's a number or not and if it is, I am ignoring it. However, my code is removing every number in a line except the first number which is `1`. I have done `line != 1 and line != '1'`. And it's just not simply catching `1`. Why does this happen? Why does my program removes every other number except `1`?

Below is a sample file.

```
1
00:00:09,068 --> 00:00:11,068
Ordinarily,
I'm a rule follower,

2
00:00:11,103 --> 00:00:12,369
But when someone tells me

3
00:00:12,404 --> 00:00:14,338
I can't bring my own snacks
into their stadium,
```

This is the result. Which `1` should not be included.

```
1
Ordinarily,
I'm a rule follower,
But when someone tells me
I can't bring my own snacks
into their stadium,
```

Below is my code

```
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if len(line.strip()) != 0 and line != 1 and line != "1":
        if (not line.isdigit()) and ('-->' not in line):
            line = del_brackets(line)
            line = ' '.join(''.join(' ' if ch in exclude else ch for ch in line).split())
            line = re.sub(r'\.\.\.', ' ', line)
            outfile.write(line.lstrip() + "\n")
```

Comment: Add a `print(repr(line))` directly after `line = line.strip()` to see the actual string content. I guess that the text file is UTF-8 encoded with a byte-order mark at the beginning.

Comment: @MichaelButscher is probably on the money, otherwise can't reproduce: https://rextester.com/FCH18014

Comment: @MichaelButscher it says "'\ufeff1\n'" what do I do with this?

Comment: @JohnSean. You edited in notepad? Not a lot of other programs voluntarily save to utf-16

Comment: What happens if you do `with open(..., encoding='utf-16') as file:`?

Comment: Also, it looks like you read in the lines with `readlines`. Don't. Show the `with` and iterate over the file object instead of preloading.

Comment: As I guessed, it is a byte-order mark as used by the different "utf" encodings. If you haven't given an `encoding` parameter to `open` yet, add one with value `"utf-8-sig"`. If you are using another encoding already, tell us which one.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I was using ```utf8``` however ```utf-8-sig``` worked for me. Still there were certain characters my program wasn't processing at all. So I did ```errors = 'ignore'```